# GestureOverlayView to Gesture

Tags: android

I am playing with gestures in android. I want to save gestures as images. I have found that there is a toBitmap method to convert gesture to image, but i can not get it working. Here is my code. I get an error on signature.toBitmap() line that toBitmap method is undefined for GestureOverlayView. Can i convert GestureOverlayView to Gesture or is there any other way??

```
  final Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.convert);
    convert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GestureOverlayView signature = (GestureOverlayView) findViewById(R.id.signature);
            signature.toBitmap();
            signature.clear(isChild());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to store the gesture and call the toBitmap() method on that rather than trying to store a bitmap off the GestureOverlayView directly?

This can be seen in the gesture builder sample application found in the android toolkit samples.

GestureBuilderActivity.java:353

```
final Bitmap bitmap = gesture.toBitmap(mThumbnailSize, mThumbnailSize,
                            mThumbnailInset, mPathColor);
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is the parameter mThumbnailInset and it's use? :)